# How to use ESP32's input-only pins with keypad library

Tags: arduino, esp32, pullup, input, keypad

I am trying to use a 1x4 keypad with an ESP32. I am using this [keypad](https://www.robotistan.com/keypad-1x4) and this [ESP32](https://urun.n11.com/arduino-urunleri-ve-setleri/esp32-30-pin-esp-wroom-32-wifi-bluetooth-cift-cekirdekli-P539760723) (30 pins); I am also using this [keypad library](https://github.com/Chris--A/Keypad).

I have only pins 14, 15, 34, 36 (VN), and 39 (VP) free on the ESP32, the others are in use.

When I think of it on paper, I should be able to use the input-only pins for the keypad.

My code looks like this and is not working. Only the "2" button is working properly.

```
#include <Keypad.h>

const byte ROWS = 1; //four rows
const byte COLS = 4; //three columns
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1', '2', '3', '4'}
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {14}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {39, 15, 34, 36}; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad

Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop() {
  char key = keypad.getKey();

  if (key) {
    Serial.println(key);
  }
}
```

Why this code is not working I do not understand, but I know pins 34, 36 and 39 are input-only pins and those pins don't have an `INPUT_PULLUP` function. But in the library there is this code in keypad.h:

```
#ifndef INPUT_PULLUP
#warning "Using  pinMode() INPUT_PULLUP AVR emulation"
#define INPUT_PULLUP 0x2
#define pinMode(_pin, _mode) _mypinMode(_pin, _mode)
#define _mypinMode(_pin, _mode)
do {                
  if (_mode == INPUT_PULLUP)
    pinMode(_pin, INPUT);
    digitalWrite(_pin, 1);
    if (_mode != INPUT_PULLUP)
      pinMode(_pin, _mode);
} while(0)
#endif
```

In my opinion this code is the problem. I've tried all the possibilities I could think of, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Do not use the keypad library because this is not a key matrix, just 4 switches. It is absurd to use 5 pins to read 4 switches. Connect the common contact to GND and the switches to 4 inputs. Enable the internal pull up resistors of these inputs (if available) or use external resistors and just read the inputs.

Comment: well if I use normal GIOP pins with  this library, everything working normal

Answer (score 1):

Pins 35, 37, 38, and 36 are input-only and do not have an internal pull-up resistor. It is required to use an external pull-up resistor in order to detect changes. Many guys talk about a 10 resistor, I just tested with a 2 kΩ one.

Hope this helps somebody.